# Is it possible to send notifications to Notification Center in Mountain Lion even when the app is not running, like in iOS?

Tags: macos, notifications, center, osx-mountain-lion

In iOS, you can register the APNS ID in a remote server; the server will use that ID with the proper certificates to send push notifications to the device even when the app that is receiving the notification is not running.

Is there a similar mechanism for OSX Mountain Lion?  Can I get a pointer to any code/sample out there?

Please note that I am not interested in local notification to the Notification Center, that is vastly discussed on the web.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the same mechanism for Mountain Lion.

Here's a good place to start:

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/push-notifications/index.html

Comment: Thanks Steve, Interesting that nothing is shown if you google or bing this question.  It must be because the topic is very recent.