# Safari website notification

Tags: safari, push-notification

In OS X safari 7 allows web site to send push notification using APNS i had research based on the links below

```
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604410/is-it-possible-to-send-notifications-to-notification-center-in-mountain-lion-eve
   https://developer.apple.com/appstore/push-notifications/index.html
   This link gives detail demo of web site notification using safari 7.
   http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/06/28/safari-70-to-bring-web-notifications-to-os-x-mavericks
```

My need, 1-> is there any possible to send web site notification using other safari versions?

2->  does push notification support only OS X safari 7? I don't want to send any local notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push Notifications supports only OS X safari 7 for details check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013225-CH3-SW1)